# where is the different vscode display image and my electron APP display image?

Tags: javascript, electron

I have a large BMP image about 30MB.
In my own electron APP, the step I display the image is :

1. fs.read  the image from local disk
2. render the img in 
   those steps almost cost 5 seconds.

In vscode, the time cost of display the same image is less than 1 second.
So, how can I reduce the time cost of image display in my electron APP?

My electron APP information:

> Build by electron-vue Electron:^2.0.4

update 2021.02.05
thanks for attention, i supply some context of this question.
How did I read image from local disk:

```
 async displayImg() {                
            let filePath = path.join(this.folderPath, this.selectedFile.filename)
            let fileData = await fs.readFileSync(filePath)
            let base64Image = new Buffer(fileData, 'binary').toString('base64')
            let imgData = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64Image;
            this.$refs.targetImg.src = imgData
        },
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please clarify on how you display the loaded image data in your app (you can [edit] your question)? Is there any reason you are not simply using an `<img>` with the path to the image file as `src`?

Comment: Can you provide code context? You may be able to provide both the function that has the call to `fs.read` or the surrounding statements of that call, and also the place where the read information is consumed if there is a difference. Even better would be to share entire files in a working prototype.

Comment: One idea in JavaScript applications generally is to use methods of console timers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console#timers

Comment: thanks for attention and i supply some context